# I am getting Git error while pushing the code

Tags: android, git, github

how to push github code error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/356gh/Green.git'
To https://github.com/356gh/Green.git
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [rejected] (non-fast-forward)
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
Done
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

[image]

Comment: you need to run command ```git pull``` command first because someone already have pushed the code that repo

Answer (score 0):

heyy Jayaraman

You need to run the `git pull`  command first as such it clearly states your commits are behind and you need to run `git fetch`  and then `git pull` command it will work for you

I hope this will work for you!!